# Cosets of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/<x²+1>$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

[This PDF](http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/quotring/quotring.pdf) says that the cosets of  $$\frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{<x²+1>}$$

looks like the following:

$$0+<x²+1>, x^{57}+x³+1+<x²+1>, (x²+1)+<x²+1>$$

Then it says that we can add and multiply cosets like the following:

$$[(x²+x+1)+<x²+1>]+[(x²+1)+<x²+1>] = x+<x²+1>$$

When you divide $2x²+x+2$ by $x²+1$ you get $x$, this is the reduction mod $x²+1$, rigth?

and

$$[(x+1)+<x²+1>][(x²+1)+<x²+1>] = (x³+x²+x+1)+<x²+1>$$

why there's no reduction mod $x²+1$ here?

Also, it says that $[(x+1)+<x²+1>][(x+1)+<x²+1>] = (x^2+1)+<x^2+1>$

what happened here? $(x+1)(x+1) = x²+2x+1$, how did it turn in $x²+1$ again?

Also, it says that since multiples of $x²+1$ are congruent to 0, we have:

$$x^2+<x²+1> = [x²+(x²+1)]+<x²+1> = 1+<x²+1>$$

what's happening???

Comment: You can use "\lange abc \rangle" to get $\langle abc \rangle$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdf does not say that those are the cosets. It says "here are some cosets."

One set of representatives of cosets is $\{0,1, x , x+1\}$. Any other representatives can be reduced to these by dividing by $x^2+1$.

Comment: but $x²+2x+1$ turned to $x²+1$, this is not reduced, the reduction gives $1$ mod $x^2+1$

Comment: $x^2 + 1 = 0$ and $2 = 0$.

Comment: @Maffred you mean $2x$? Also $x²+2x+1$ mod $x²+1$ won't give $1$?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I don't understand the context of your comments so far. In your ring, $2=0$ so that $x^2+2x+1=0$ in your ring.

Comment: You can write your ring this way $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{(2,X^2 + 1)}$, ie a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Now everything should be more clear.

Comment: $[(x+1)+<x²+1>][(x+1)+<x²+1>] = (x^2+2x+1)+<x^2+1>$ now, if I want to reduce $x²+2x+1$ shouldn't I just find out that $x²+2x+1 = 2x(x²+1)+1$ so $x²+2x+1$ is congruent to $1$ mod $x²+1$?

Comment: You did calculation wrong! It's $+ 1$, why $+2$?

Comment: Your multiplication is $(x+1)^2 +$ a multiple of $(x^2 + 1)$ thus $X^2 + 2X + 1 +$ a multiple of $(x^2 + 1)$.

Comment: @Maffred how is $(x+1)²$ a multiple of $x²+1$?

Comment: They are equal: $(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 1$ cause 2=0 because you are working with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @Maffred I tottaly forgot that I was in $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Comment: As I said, a different way to write your ring is $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with the relations $2=0$ and $x^2 + 1 =0$.

Answer (score 0):

You have polinomyals with coefficents in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and the relation $X^2 + 1 = 0$, in other words $X^2 = -1$. So you can reduce every polinomyal by replacing the above equivalence several times. You only get elements of the form $aX + b$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ thus there are only $4$ representatives, namely $0, 1, X, X+1$. Note that in this ring with $4$ elements you get $(X+1)^2 = X^2 + 2X + 1 = -1 + 0 + 1 = 0$, thus this is not an integral domain (nor a field).

Comment: I don't quite get why I can do this replacement :c

Comment: When you make a quotient is like you say that what is under, is in the same equivalence class of $0$, ie in the quozient it is $0$. It's like $9 \equiv 0 (mod 3)$ in the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/3$. You are saying $x^2 + 1 \equiv 0 (mod x^2+1)$ or $x^2 \equiv -1 (mod x^2+1)$.